# why does these toupper work different when utilized like this?

Tags: c++, toupper

why does one give me an int and the other doesn't?:

```
    toupper(member_names[2]);
```

and:

```
    member_names[2] = toupper(member_names[2]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toupper` takes a character (encoded into an `int` for mostly-historical reasons) and returns the upper-case equivalent of that character.

Therefore, your first version doesn't really accomplish anything. Your second converts `member_names[2]` to its upper-case equivalent.

Also note that (in most implementations) a `char` can have a negative value (e.g., accented characters in ISO 8859-*). Passing a negative value to `toupper` can/will lead to (serious) problems--unless `member_names` is an array of `unsigned char`, you normally want to case to `unsigned char` before passing to `toupper`:

```
member_names[2] = toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(member_names[2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `toupper` function does not modify its argument.
So this call:

```
toupper(member_names[2]);
```

returns a value that you ignore.

The other version is taking the value from the `toupper` function and assigning it to `member_names[2]` thus modifying the previous value.